# PhoneGap Media Record Audio and Upload to Server

Tags: cordova, audio, mobile, phonegap-plugins, record

I'm using the following PhoneGap Media code to record audio in my app. I'm able to record the audio and play it back just fine. I need to be able to send the recorded file to my server when done (preferably using PhoneGap's File Transfer plugin http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer), however I'm not quite sure how to write File Transfer code. Below is the code I'm currently using to record the file. After doing some searching, I found that File Transfer will only work with this by locating the path of the recorded file on my device, but nothing I've tried so far has been successful. Any help on this would be great, thanks.

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Record audio
// 
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.wav";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();


    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime >= 10) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    recordAudio();
}

// onSuccess Callback
//
function onSuccess() {
    alert("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    console.log(filePath);
}

// onError Callback 
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Set audio position
// 
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use the file-transfer plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer